# Unusual $n\rightarrow0$ limit of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

I want to explain the following limit:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k \stackrel{n\ll1\\}{\,\,\,=\,\,\,}n\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}a_k+o(n)
$$
Is there a simple way to prove it? The unusual thing is that $n$ is considered a natural number at the beginning, to properly define the sum from 1 to $n$, while to do the limit a sort of analytical continuation of $n$ to real numbers is needed.

(I'm studying the following paper: https://hal.science/jpa-00232897/document , the authors use the previous limit between Eqs. (15) and (16).  The continuation for $n$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ was shown to be correct in some applications to statistical mechanics of disordered systems. )

**Edit**

As pointed out in a comment, it is possible to perform the $n\rightarrow0$ limit for the so-called "generalized binomial coefficients":
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k}=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}
$$
The result of the whole limit in the first equation is therefore reasonable, but a question still holds: why the sum from 1 to $n$ become a sum from 1 to $\infty$ as $n\rightarrow0$?

Comment: What you wrote has no sense... the LHS is not depending on $n$ whereas the RHS does...

Comment: I'm sorry, the notation is a bit sloppy, anyway I changed the equation, this should be more correct

Comment: It is still very obscure to me. especially in the case $0<n<1$, how is the first sum defined, and the binomial coefficients?

Comment: Yes, I admit that it is not immediate to understand. On the other hand a lot of (also formal) results has been proved using this analytic continuation from $n\in\mathbb{N}$ to $n\in\mathbb{R}$ in the field of statistical mechanics of disordered systems. Studying related papers I found more than once this kind of limit but it was simpler than this case, so I asked the question. Maybe the factorials can be written as Euler Gamma functions, this can be a starting point.

Comment: Intuitively, $\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{1}{n}\binom{n}{k} = \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$ (for generalized binomial coefficients) makes this believeable.

Comment: Ah, thanks @nasekatnasushi. What about the sum in front? Why should that become a sum from 1 to $\infty$?